# Content-Security-Policy suddenly stopped working while using the app

Tags: cordova, android-webview, content-security-policy

I'm working on a Cordova app for months and I've never had any problem with the Content-Security-Policy after setting it the way I wanted, months ago.

My app connects to the server when I launch it. It's the same server for months.

But today it suddenly stopped working while I was using the app. My app crashed (first time it happens) then when I relaunched it, I had the CSP error when trying to connect to the server.

I didn't change the CSP, I wasn't even working on that at all.

I tried restarting my phone and the server but it didn't solve the problem.

So the address I want to connect to is something like `http://my.random.address.com:40017/4DSOAP`

My CSP is `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' http://*/4DSOAP https://*/4DSOAP" />`.

As I said it worked perfectly fine for months, I'm connecting to the server hundreds of times per week, including dozens of times just for today.

Now if I change the CSP to `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' http://my.random.address.com:40017/4DSOAP https://*/4DSOAP" />` (so the exact address I'm trying to reach), it works. But this is not what i want because it can be another port or even another address.

The error on Chrome Debug is:

> Refused to connect to 'http://my.random.address.com:40017/4DSOAP' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' http:// * /4DSOAP https:// * /4DSOAP". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Is it possible my phone made an update when I was using the app, an update that changed the webview and the way CSP work (maybe asterisks not allowed anymore or working differently)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I solved it by changing the CSP to:

> http://*:*/4DSOAP https://*:*/4DSOAP" />

So instead of an asterisk, I have two: one for the IP and one for the port.

I still dunno why it suddenly stopped working the way it was.